# How to order database columns in Rails when using MySQL database with json datatype?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json

I have the model Job and Job model have field additional_data. Here additional_data column is stored as json data type and have field like "priority". I want to order jobs table entries based on additional_data's "priority" field value. I have code like following but it's not working. I need to order using ORM not by raw sql.

```
@jobs = Job.all.order('additional_data['priority'] asc')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Query Order By Value in JSON Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645100/mysql-query-order-by-value-in-json-column)

Comment: I'm asking how to order using Rails ORM.

Answer (score 0):

This post is already 4 months old but maybe this can still make someone happy.
You could do something like this.

```
@jobs = Job.all
.select('*, JSON_EXTRACT(additional_data, "$.priority") AS priority')
.order('priority asc')
```